# OpenX php fatal error when APC is enabled

Tags: php, apc, openx

I am trying to migrate openX from a RHEL server to an Ubuntu based.

I am hitting the following error whenever APC is enabled:

Fatal error: Interface 'OX_M2M_M2MTicketProvider' not found in /var/www/openx/lib/OA/Central/M2MTicketProviderImpl.php on line 33

as soon as I switch apc off, everything works fine.

has anybody encountered this?

thanks in advance

UPDATE: This actually only happens when apc.stat=0. It is probably worth mentioning that the config file is symlinked to a shared storage (glusterFS)

UPDATE 2:
On M2MTicketProviderImpl.php if I change

require_once (dirname ( **FILE** ) . "../../../OX/M2M/M2MTicketProvider.php");

to

require_once (LIB_PATH . "/../OX/M2M/M2MTicketProvider.php");

it works.

But I would like to find a solution where I dont need to hack the openX code.

Answer (score 2):

simple solution for that is settings:

```
apc.include_once_override = 0
```